# Extracting from sub matrix

Tags: r, matrix

```
mat = replicate (100,{x = matrix(data = rep(NA, 80), ncol = 2)})
for (k in 1:100)
{
mat[,,k]<-out$'k'$position
}
mat
```

> Error in mat[, , k] <- out$’k’$position : 
>        number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

It works fine for `mat[,,1]<-out$’1’$position` but when I loop over it 100 times, the error occurs.

Comment: I was going to try your update, when you posted a new question

Comment: Instead of `$` you need `out[[k]]$position`

Comment: @akrun- Thanks a lot. This error is resolved but still in previous question after making this change in code I am unable to get different values for 's' and 'cost' for each k. I would be grateful if you try for previous updated question

Comment: I will check there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `[[` instead of `$`

```
for(k in 1:100) mat[,,k] <- out[[k]]$position
head(mat[,,1])
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4   10
#[2,]    4    9
#[3,]    4    8
#[4,]    1   10
#[5,]    4    7
#[6,]    1    9
```